# How does the VS Code debugger attach to an already running node process?

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger

How is Visual Studio Code debugger able to attach to a already running node process?

I simply used `npm start` to run my node application and then use the VS Code "attach to process Id" launch configuration to start the debugger. I didn't had to start my application with `--inspect` or `--debug` flag. How is this actually working?

Answer (score 2):

As can be found in the nodejs [docs](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/):

> Node.js will also start listening for debugging messages if it receives a SIGUSR1 signal. (SIGUSR1 is not available on Windows.) In Node.js 7 and earlier, this activates the legacy Debugger API. In Node.js 8 and later, it will activate the Inspector API.

VS Code sends `SIGUSR1` to the process. From the VS Code [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes):

> the debugger tries to attach to this process after having sent a USR1
> signal. With this setting, the debugger can attach to an already
> running process that was not started in debug mode.